# Como calcular a soma acumulada no Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Olá,

Tenho uma tabela com muitos dados, e gostaria de contar a quantidade de registros em cada data deste mês. Até aqui OK, um `COUNT(*)` e um `GROUP BY` já resolve.

```
SELECT
    Trunc(td.data_emissao) AS data_emissao
    ,Count(*) AS quantidade
FROM
    tabela_de_dados td
WHERE
    Trunc(td.data_emissao,'mm') = Trunc(Sysdate,'mm')
GROUP BY
    Trunc(td.data_emissao)
ORDER BY
    1 ASC
;
```

Mas também preciso saber a **quantidade acumulada**, exemplo; a quantidade do dia 2 é a soma dos registros do dia 1 até o dia 2, e assim por diante, até que no último dia eu tenha o total de registros do mês.

No fim, eu gostaria de retornar a tabela abaixo, como exemplo

```
Data_emissao | Quantidade | Quantidade Acumulada
--------------------------------------------------
01/04        | 10         | 10
02/04        | 25         | 35
03/04        | 15         | 50
04/04        | 30         | 80
...          | ...        | ...
```

E assim por diante do mês inteiro. Espero ter esclarecido a dúvida.

Comment: Não seria o mesmo `count(*)` porém sem agrupar por data, apenas deixando na condição `where` o mês  e o ano que deseja o total? Não sei se entendi bem sua dúvida.

Comment: Funcionaria sim, se eu buscasse dia a dia o total até aquele momento. Mas o que eu preciso são as duas informações na mesma tabela. Exemplo Data 01/04 Registros 10 Registros Acumulados 10; Data 02/04 Registros 25 Registros Acumulados 35 - e assim por diante

Comment: Pesquise por "Analytic Function Oracle OVER()"

Comment: Obrigado @motta! Consegui!

Comment: Analytic Function permitem relatórios muito úteis !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui usando "Analytic Function Oracle" "Sum() Over()"

```
    select
       trunc(td.data_emissao) as data_emissao
       ,count(*) as emitidos
       ,sum(count(*)) over(order by trunc(td.data_emissao) rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as emitidos_acumulado
    from
       tabela_de_dados td
    where
       trunc(td.data_emissao,'mm') = trunc(sysdade,'mm')
    group by
       trunc(td.data_emissao)
```

Answer (score 2):

Tente:

```
SELECT
    Trunc(td.data_emissao) AS data_emissao,
    Count(*) AS quantidade,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM tabela_dados tda 
     WHERE tda.trunc_emissao <= td.data_emissao AND Trunc(tda.data_emissao,'mm') = Trunc(Sysdate,'mm')) AS qtd_acumulada
FROM
    tabela_de_dados td
WHERE
    Trunc(td.data_emissao,'mm') = Trunc(Sysdate,'mm')
GROUP BY
    Trunc(td.data_emissao)
ORDER BY
    1 ASC
;
```